# Perl search and replace files in-place with or without the diamond op

Tags: regex, perl, file-io

I am trying to replicate in a script the classic one-liner:

```
perl -i -p -e 's/search_string/replace_string/g' /path/to/file/foo
```

which replaces all occurrences of "search_string" in `foo` with "replace_string".

I tried with:

```
@ARGV=("/path/to/file/foo");
$^I  = ".bak";
while (<>) {
   s/search_string/replace_string/g; 
   print; 
}
```

This works but, if I need to access again to command line arguments, I lose `@ARGV` values. Therefore I need to backup them:

```
my @temp=@ARGV;
@ARGV=("/path/to/file/foo");
$^I  = ".bak";
while (<>) {
   s/search_string/replace_string/g; 
   print; 
}
@ARGV=@temp;
```

Also this works but, as I am very new to Perl, I find it too convoluted and a bit against making "easy things easy and hard things possible".
Can you suggest a better way?

Comment: @TLP: Say the last is `test.pl`. If I add an extra line like `print "@ARGV\n";`, `test.pl arg1 arg2 arg3`  will repalce in  `foo` and  print the `arg1 arg2 arg3`.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-can-I-use-Perl's--i-option-from-within-a-program%3f

Comment: The behaviour of the `-i` switch is described in detail in [perldoc perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To temporarily backup a package variable, use `local`.

```
{
   local @ARGV = ( "/path/to/file/foo" );
   local $^I  = ".bak";
   while (<>) {
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Great use case for `local`

Answer (score 0):

If you're taking command line arguments to a script then recommend using the [GetOpt](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Std.html) module. That way you can read arguments into a variable and not have to worry about overwriting `@ARGV`.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.0100;
use Getopt::Std;

# Filename argument
my $opt_f;

getopts( 'f:' );

say "My file is $opt_f";
```

Then run it like this:

```
~> ./foo.pl -f oogada
My file is oogada
```